# Get query instead of replace foreign key by name in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Get query instead of replace foreign key by name in laravel.Get record replacement of menu_id to menu_name.Menu table contains id and menu_name.

```
 "cart_items": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "cart_id": 1,
                "menu_id": 5,
                "quantity": "3",
                "amount": "150",
                "created_at": "2019-09-04 09:45:28",
                "updated_at": "2019-09-04 09:45:28"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "cart_id": 1,
                "menu_id": 4,
                "quantity": "3",
                "amount": "150",
                "created_at": "2019-09-04 09:54:32",
                "updated_at": "2019-09-04 09:54:32"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Could you please tell where you face the problem? and please share what you have done so far....

Comment: My problem is i fetch record from cart_items table then menu_id is an foreign key.Instead of menu_id i get record with menu_name.

Comment: but  I dont see menu_name in what you paste, please paste your code because now we can only guess what you need

Comment: Menu table contains only two column id and name.In the above code is cart table i save menu_id as foreign key.I need to fetch all data in cart table.While fetching i need to get menu_name in menu_id column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use with method while fetching query.Its works

```
$data['cart_items'] = CartItem::with('menu')->where('cart_id',$cart->id)->get();
```

In my CartItem model i use eloquent orm function:

```
public function menu()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Menu','id','menu_id')->select(['id','menu_name']);
    }
```

It returns output:

```
"cart_items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "cart_id": 1,
            "menu_id": 5,
            "quantity": "3",
            "amount": "150",
            "created_at": "2019-09-04 09:45:28",
            "updated_at": "2019-09-04 09:45:28",
            "menu": {
                "id": 5,
                "menu_name": "PODI IDLI"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "cart_id": 1,
            "menu_id": 4,
            "quantity": "3",
            "amount": "150",
            "created_at": "2019-09-04 09:54:32",
            "updated_at": "2019-09-04 09:54:32",
            "menu": {
                "id": 4,
                "menu_name": "CORN PANEER MIX VEG SALAD WITH SAUSAGE"
            }
        }]
```

Comment: How about an already fetched record? Sth like `$cart_item->with('menu')`

Answer (score 2):

use [Laravel mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators) to add menu_name for object, and add menu_id to $hidden =['manu_id']; in the model class